# using PHP and JS to fetch data for an entry

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I need to fetch some data from a mysql database. For that I created get_data.php on the server and a js function to retrieve that data on the client. Is this the proper way to do it? What would you change?

get_data.php

```php
<?php
    require_once('database.php');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || !isset($_POST['entryID'])){
        exit('Bad request data');
    }

    $db = db_connect();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `data` FROM `entries` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1;");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['entryID']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();

    if ($res->num_rows > 0){
        $arr = $res->fetch_assoc();
        $json = array('status'=> 1, 'data'=>$arr['data']);
    }else{
        $json = array('status'=> 0);
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Code to fetch that data in javascript:

```js
function getRemoteData(entryID) {
    const defaultErrorMessage = '## This page isn\'t ready (yet)';

    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('entryID', entryID);

    const d = fetch(requestUrl + '/get_data.php',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: form,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            if (json.status == 1 && json.data != "")
                return gunzipString(json.data);

            return defaultErrorMessage;
        });

    return d;
}
```

It works fine but I'm not sure I'm doing things properly.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not wrong, you're missing `header("Content-Type: application/json");`. If you don't do this, most of the clients will work but some low-level clients might fail.

Also, you can optionally add `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header to increase your backend's security level.

Plus, you should return a JSON response and set the HTTP status to `400 Bad Request` instead of just exiting out (line 6) like this:

```php
header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
echo json_encode(['status' => -1, 'message' => "Bad request"]);
exit();
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change much. As was suggested by [ArRakin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/273581/120114) using more headers is a good idea. The sample code in that answer uses the [short array syntax](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func) [introduced in PHP 5.4](https://www.php.net/releases/5_4_0.php). There isn't anything wrong with using the longer syntax but the short syntax can make line length shorter overall, and may be more comfortable for anyone working with JSON and/or JavaScript.

One minor point to consider is spacing. Compare the spacing on the arrays in the following lines:

> ```
> $json = array('status'=> 1, 'data'=>$arr['data']);
> ```

and

> ```
> $json = array('status'=> 0);
> ```

Some developers follow the PSRs like [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/), which recommends:

> ### 6.2. Binary operators
>
> All binary [arithmetic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), [logical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), and [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) operators MUST be preceded and followed by at least one space.

For the sake of readability, use a space before and after operators including `=>`.

In the JavaScript code, the variable `d` is only used once - i.e. when returned. Single-use variable often can be eliminated - e.g. instead of assigning the return from `fetch()` just return it:

```
return fetch(requestUrl + '/get_data.php',
```